# .doc to plain text converter

Tags: c++

Is there any c/c++ open source library available to convert MSWord .doc/.docx files to plain text format?

Comment: Michael Palin or Sarah Palin?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: You could look into invoking Libre Office on the command line instead. Iirc it has a headless version.

Answer (score 2):

These are not actually libraries, but might still be useful. There are 2 console applications that I am aware of [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) and [catdoc](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/catdoc/). Antiword is GPL, catdoc source is also available, but I'm not sure about the license. These are written in C, so using these from C++ should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, a .docx file is actually a ZIP file with several directories in it. One of the files in one of those directories has the document text in it, as XML with markup. There are some tags you have to handle because they mark the line ends, but most of them mark where autocorrect has flagged various things, or the randomly-distributed 5-level-deep nested tags that markup formatting.

(I had to do this by hand once on a machine with no Internet access. Someone saved a file with Office 2011 and wanted to open it on Office 2005 or so at a friend's place out in the boonies.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a library for this task but perhaps you can extract the important bits from [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/). I'm not sure Antiword handles docx, though.